# SQL Developer - how duplicate data in months between data date ranges?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called "TRENDING" which stores information about my employee and any changes that have happened with a start and end date. I want to get the Start and End date for each row for each employee and want to duplicated so i can evaluate by month each employee record. Example below.

This is an example of one employee, but the data stores multiple employees and each employee can have multiple changes or effective start and end date. This is an example:

Note in the example below since employee effective_start_date  is already past the 1st of the month (May) it will not consider may, but if it is between the range it will AS 30-APR-17 it did generate one for May.

Trending Table:

| employee_number | job_name | salary_rate | effective_start_date | effective_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |

Output:

| Month | Year | employee_number | job_name | salary_rate | effective_start_date | effective_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 07 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 08 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 09 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 10 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 11 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 12 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 01 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 02 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 03 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 04 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100,000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
| 05 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
| 06 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
| 07 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
| 08 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
| 09 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
| 10 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
| 11 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
| 12 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120,000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution. To improve this question, please include what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH trending_months (month_year, employee_number, job_name, salary_rate, effective_start_date, effective_end_date) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(effective_start_date - 1, 'MM'), 1),
         employee_number,
         job_name,
         salary_rate,
         effective_start_date,
         effective_end_date
  FROM   trending
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(month_year, 1),
         employee_number,
         job_name,
         salary_rate,
         effective_start_date,
         effective_end_date
  FROM   trending_months
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(month_year, 1) <= effective_end_date
)
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month_year) AS month,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM month_year) AS year,
       employee_number,
       job_name,
       salary_rate,
       effective_start_date,
       effective_end_date
FROM   trending_months
ORDER BY effective_start_date, effective_end_date, year, month
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE trending (employee_number, job_name, salary_rate, effective_start_date, effective_end_date) AS
SELECT 10, 'Engineer', 100000, DATE '2016-05-23', DATE '2017-04-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Engineer', 120000, DATE '2017-04-30', DATE '2017-12-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MONTH | YEAR | EMPLOYEE_NUMBER | JOB_NAME | SALARY_RATE | EFFECTIVE_START_DATE | EFFECTIVE_END_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 6 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 7 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 8 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 9 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 10 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 11 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 12 | 2016 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 1 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 2 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 3 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 4 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 100000 | 23-MAY-16 | 29-APR-17 |
> | 5 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
> | 6 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
> | 7 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
> | 8 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
> | 9 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
> | 10 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
> | 11 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |
> | 12 | 2017 | 10 | Engineer | 120000 | 30-APR-17 | 31-DEC-17 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a3840f15a8f408dfb676dede2beddd9)*

Answer (score 0):

You want a recursive query to get from date ranges to months.

```
with monthly (employee_number, job_name, salary_rate, 
              effective_start_date, effective_end_date, first_day_of_month) as
(
  select
    employee_number, job_name, salary_rate,
    effective_start_date, effective_end_date,
    case when extract(day from effective_start_date) = 1 then
      trunc(effective_start_date, 'mm')
    else
      trunc(effective_start_date, 'mm') + interval '1' month
    end as first_day_of_month
  from trending
  union all
  select
    employee_number, job_name, salary_rate,
    effective_start_date, effective_end_date,
    first_day_of_month + interval '1' month
  from monthly
  where first_day_of_month + interval '1' month <= effective_end_date
)
select
  extract(month from first_day_of_month) as month,
  extract(year from first_day_of_month) as year,
  employee_number, job_name, salary_rate,
  effective_start_date, effective_end_date
from monthly
order by first_day_of_month;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=233b8521fada6c977dc375f2f83e1541

Comment: Don't use `+ INTERVAL '1' MONTH` as it fails when the start date is, for example, `2017-01-30`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99ec61bc556b60a11f3a90f98d2c3771)

Comment: @MT0: Damn. Thank you. That looked so simple. I'll update my answer.